# Как вывести ошибку Forbidden discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Здраствуйте!
Не знаю как вывести ошибку `discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions`. Различные методы пробовал, через `cog_command_error()` и `isinstance(error, Forbidden)` и `isinstanse(error, BotMissingPermissions)`, но ничего не вышло.
Я делаю это для того, что бы бот отсылал сообщение если у него нет доступа до той или иной команды.

Вот мой код:

```
async def cog_command_error(self, ctx: Context, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        user = ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.author.id)
        await user.send('У бота нет доступа до этой команды. Дайте эму доступ `Банить учасников`')

    if isinstance(error, commands.MissingPermissions):
        kick_emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка!', color =0xff060e)
        kick_emb.add_field(
            name = 'Причина ошибки:',
            value = 'У вас нету нужных прав для управления этой командой!',
            inline = False
        )
        await ctx.send(embed = kick_emb)
        
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MemberNotFound):
        kick_emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка!', color = 0xff060e)
        kick_emb.add_field(
            name = 'Причина ошибки:',
            value = 'Не указано имя пользователя',
            inline = False
        )
        kick_emb.add_field(
            name = 'Пример использования команды:',
            value = '{}ban @user reason', inline = False
        )
        await ctx.send(embed = kick_emb)
        
    if isinstance(error, commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument):
        kick_emb = discord.Embed(title = 'Ошибка!', color =0xff060e)
        kick_emb.add_field(
            name = 'Причина ошибки:',
            value = 'Не указана причина',
            inline = False
        )
        kick_emb.add_field(
            name = 'Пример использования команды:',
            value = '{}ban @user reason',
            inline = False
        )
        await ctx.send(embed = kick_emb)
```

Traceback:

```
File "f:\discord bot\cogs\utils\clear.py", line 23, in _clear
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit = self.quantity + 1)
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 383, in purge
    await strategy(to_delete)
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\channel.py", line 301, in delete_messages
    await self._state.http.delete_messages(self.id, message_ids)
  File "C:\Users\123\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\discord\http.py", line 248, in request
    raise Forbidden(r, data)
discord.errors.Forbidden: 403 Forbidden (error code: 50013): Missing Permissions
```

Как можно решить мою проблему?

Comment: `from discord.errors import Forbidden 

try: smth except Forbidden: pass`

Comment: @ClarkDevlin, не работает(не выводит сообщения `user = ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.author.id)
            await user.send('У бота нет доступа до этой команды. Дайте ему доступ Банить участников')`), все одно в консоль ошибку выкидывает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@commands.bot_has_permissions(ban_members = True, manage_messages = True)
```

Добавляете этот рядок где указываете права бота с которыми он сможет использовать ету команду, после этого в ошибках прописываете следующе:

```
if isinstance(error, BotMissingPermissions):
    ...
```

И все.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте сделать отправление сообщений об ошибках через ивент [`on_command_error`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=cog_command_error#discord.on_command_error).

```
from discord.ext import commands


class Listeners(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_command_error(self, ctx: commands.Context, error):
       if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
          user = ctx.guild.get_member(ctx.author.id)
          await user.send('У бота нет доступа до этой команды. Дайте эму доступ `Банить учасников`')
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте использовать декоратор `@{тут название функции}.error`.

```
@kick.error
async def kick_error(self, ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.BotMissingPermissions):
        # Тут код, если у бота нет прав
```

Comment: Это не помогало, нашел уже способ как решить проблему, вскоре добавлю сюда